# Exclude post formats in custom loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-formats

I'm trying to exclude all post formats but standard from a page template loop that displays 4 latest posts. For some reason I can't get the query to work.

This is my page template

```
global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
$args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) ) {
$wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
$paged = $args['paged'];
}

 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 query_posts('cat=0&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged); //set your own query here
 get_template_part( 'loop', 'portfolio' );

 wp_reset_query();
```

This is the loop

```
<?php $num_cols = 4; // set the number of columns here

for ( $i=1 ; $i <= $num_cols; $i++ ) :
    echo '<div class="column col-' . $i . '" >';
    $counter = $num_cols + 1 - $i; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    if( $counter%$num_cols == 0 ) :

// begin of core posts output ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
    POST STUFF
    <?php //end of posts output

    endif; $counter++;
        endwhile;
            rewind_posts();
        echo '</div>'; //closes the column div
    endfor; ?>
        <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 || get_query_var('page')) : ?>
            <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>           
        <?php endif;
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is the query I've been trying to get to work with it

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside', 'post-format-image' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$args=array(
    'paged'=>$paged, //Pulls the paged function into the query
    'posts_per_page'=> 4, //Limits the amount of posts on each page
    'post_type'=>'post_type', //Set your allowed post types here
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

query_posts($args);
```

For more reference refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters).

You can pass the allowed post_type array to `post_type` argument in arguments array.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for post types and not post formats? I need to exclude all formats but the standard post format